# Create a comma separated list of clicked elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, csv

I'm trying to inject a comma separated list into the DOM that a user can copy and paste into another application. Right now I'm completely stuck on how to handle the first element which is not preceded by a comma.

Right now a user clicks on an element and jquery grabs the ID of the element to build the list. The user should be able to toggle their selections on and off. I also need the list to be generated in the order that the user selects items.

HTML

```
Comma separated list here: <span id="list"></span>
<br />
<a id="1" class="clickme" href="#"><li>One</li></a>
<a id="2" class="clickme" href="#"><li>Two</li></a>
<a id="3" class="clickme" href="#"><li>Three</li></a>
<a id="4" class="clickme" href="#"><li>Four</li></a>
<a id="5" class="clickme" href="#"><li>Five</li></a>
<a id="6" class="clickme" href="#"><li>Six</li></a>
```

CSS

```
.selected {
    background-color: #99CCFF;    
}
```

JS - jquery is loaded

```
$('.clickme').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var book_id = $(this).attr('id'); 
        $(this).children('li').toggleClass("selected");
        var list_container = $("#list");
        if ($(this).children('li').is(".selected")) {
            if (list_container.text().length > 0) {
                list_container.append("," + book_id);
            } else {
                list_container.append(book_id);
            }
        } else {
            list_container.text(list_container.text().replace("," + book_id, ""));          
        }
});
```

This works great to build the comma separated list and it works great to toggle off all but the first value in the list. The problem is that the first value was inserted without a preceding comma and so the replace function can't match it. If I remove the comma from the replace function then I'm left with a bunch of unneeded commas. If I match both then I run the risk of matching part of an ID...ie replacing the 3 in 13 when the 3 is toggled off.

I've tried a ton of variations and can't find anything that works.

My only solution that produced the desired result was to use CSS to inject the commas and wrap the injected IDs with a span element.

CSS TRICK

```
#list span { display: inline; }
#list span:after { content: ","; }
#list span:last-child:after { content: ""; }
```

Worked great...except for the actual purpose of this. I need users to be able to copy and paste the generated string. When you use CSS to produce the content the DOM level clipboards in most browsers don't see it. IE copied the string as you see it in the browser, FF and Safari both copied the string without the CSS appended commas.

[Fiddle is HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rYu6m/1/)

Comment: You can't have `<li>` tags outside of a `<ul>` (or `<ol>`) like that.

Comment: correct...this was just the markup for this block of code dealing with the issue I'm having. It lives inside of a UL

Comment: `<li>` tags can *only* be direct children of a `<ul>`.  Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/li#Examples

`<ul><li><a></a><li></ul>` is valid, `<ul><a><li></li></a></ul>` is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are way over complicating this problem.  Just simply make an array of selected book ids then use `.join(',')` to display them as a comma-separated list.

```
$('.clickme').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('li').toggleClass("selected");

    var list_container = $("#list");
    var book_ids = $('.clickme:has(li.selected)').map(function(){
        return this.id;
    }).get();

    list_container.text(book_ids.join(','));
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rYu6m/2/

EDIT: You say you want to keep the elements in the order they were clicked.  In that case, you need to declare the array outside the click handler, then either `.push` the element onto it or `.splice` it out.    It's much easier to work with arrays, than to work with strings.

```
var book_ids = [];
$('.clickme').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('li').toggleClass("selected");

    var list_container = $("#list");

    var index = $.inArray(this.id, book_ids);
    if(index === -1){
        // Not in array, add it
        book_ids.push(this.id);
    }
    else{
        // In the array, remove it
        book_ids.splice(index, 1);
    }

    list_container.text(book_ids.join(','));
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rYu6m/4/

Comment: This solution is very good for what I wrote in my question. I was not aware of the map() function...I can see a ton of uses for it...can't believe I've never seen it before. My issue with this solution is that it does not preserve the order that the elements are clicked in. I did not list that as a requirement because I didn't know there was a method that wouldn't preserve it! I'm modifying my question to add that requirement.

Comment: @user2027355: If you want to keep the order, you need to declare the array outside the handler, and then append to it / remove from it.

Comment: @user2027355: Glad I could help :-D

Answer (score 2):

Rocket Hazmat's solution is very similar and probably better, but i'll post mine anyway:

```
$('.clickme').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var l = [];
    $('.selected').each(function(){
        l.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $('#list').text(l.join(','));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rYu6m/3/